# How to reinitialize an array to null in .net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a double() and once I'm done using it I want to use it again by setting the array to null. Apparently that's a terrible practice to do in .net so what's the right way to reinitialize an array back to nothing?

Array.clear leaves me with an array of zeros. This variable can be used by the entire class so creating a new array doesn't answer the question either. The code below shows how the variable is used. It's used in multiple methods. I hope this example explains what I'm trying to ask.

```
class foo
    private dim myArray as new double()

    public sub createArrayFromFile()
        If(not isNothing(myArray))
           //set myarray to null. what's this code?
        End If
        //Add data to myArray by parsing a file

    end sub

    public sub createArrayFromMachine()
        If(not isNothing(myArray))
           //set myarray to null. what's this code?
        End If
        //Add data to the array from a machine
    end sub

    public sub sendToDB()
        if(not isNothing(myarray)
           //code that puts the data into the database
        end if
    end sub
end class
```

Comment: It would really help if you could post your code. Perhaps you should just create a new array? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: An array is written as `double[]`, not `double()`; the latter is a method. Give us a source for this "terrible practice", I find that a very curious statement.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel OP might be talking about VB.Net, where `()` is used for arrays (and methods, and properties).

Comment: @sloth That's correct.

Comment: Then you might want to mark what language dialect you're using, in the question, so there aren't any misunderstandings. :)

Comment: What am I really trying to achieve? I want to set the array to null so I can reuse it again. I can't redim it and it also seems like you can't set it to null. So how do you take an array with data in it and wipe everything out of it?

Comment: `I want to set the array to null so I can reuse it again` this is a terrible practice. Back in the past, people were using "global variables", which is the same. Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was exactly what I was looking for

```
myArray = nothing
```

Comment: Statements like this lead to unmaintainable code, and headache for future developers supporting your application.

Comment: True. In spirit of answering the question. This is it. After reading your comment though, I refactored and created a new object so now I'm passing around and referencing only this local variable. It still leaves me with a global variable, but now I'm only assigning to it and referencing one time.

Answer (score 2):

You can either simply create a new array and let the garbage collector do its work:

```
my_array = {} ' create a new, empty array '
```

or, if you want to reuse and clear your array, use the [`Array.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

> **Array.Clear Method**
>
> Sets a range of elements in an array to the default value of each element type.

or change its size:

```
ReDim my_array(-1) ' delete all elements and set size to 0 or whatever '
```

Comment: I did try that at first, but that only set all of the elements to zero.

Comment: `double` is a value type so the array values can't be null. When you create a new array of double, it's created with zeros. If you want to be able to set the values to null, you can use an array of `double?` instead.

Comment: @user2567273 Then why not simply create a new array?

Comment: So "?" would allow you to set a double() (or whatever array of primitive type I guess) to null?

Comment: @user2567273 Adi Lester talks about creating an array of `double?` instead of `double`. `double?` is a nullable type, hence a value of type `double?` can be `Nothing`. I still don't get your problem. You can of course set an array variable to `Nothing` and you can also just change the size of an already existing array with `ReDim`.

Comment: @sloth What's the syntax for setting a variable as a new array after data has been added to it?? I did try redim but I was surprised when it told me you can't use redim to declare array variables.

Comment: if your variable is e.g. called `my_array`, you can simply use `my_array = {}` to create a new, empty array, or `ReDim my_array(-1)` to delete all elements from the existing array and set it size to `0`.

Comment: my_array = {} creates an "value of type '1-Dimensional array of Object' cannot be convert to 'Double'" message.
Redim my_array(-1) creates an "'Redim' statement requires an array" message.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to worry about managing memory in .NET in this case (and in most other cases as well). If you leave an array full of data when your program ends, it will be released automatically by the garbage collector.

Learn about managing the scope of your variables. Always declare your variables at the right level, to let garbage collector release the associated memory as soon as possible.

If you need to reuse the same variable for a different purpose, think again. In most cases it's best to declare a different variable instead. If you are looping, and need a new array every time, declare an array inside the loop, so when it goes to next iteration, it's cleaned up automatically.

**EDIT:** Regarding your question edit, here is how you can do it:

```
class foo
  private dim myArray as new double()

  public function foobar() as new double()
    Dim myArrayLocal1 As new double()
    'Add some stuff to the myArrayLocal1 
    If smth then Return myArrayLocal1

    Dim myArrayLocal2 As new double()
    'Add some stuff to the myArrayLocal2 
    Return myArrayLocal2 
  end sub

  'then do this myArray = foobar
end class
```

The function can also probably be declared `Shared`. Although it really looks like you need two separate functions in this case. For me to give you a more concrete example, please add more detail about the actual "some stuff" code.

Comment: I come from the world of Java so maybe I'm missing something completely that I can't do in VB.net. Given the scope of the variable in question (check out the example I added) creating a new variable won't work.

Comment: @user2567273: You can do a lot of things in VB.NET, but there is only a subset of those you should use, if you want to keep your code clean. Check my edit.

Comment: Oh I absolutely agree with you there. So many more things you can do "out of the box" in VB.NET. I hope my modified code example gives more insight on what's going on.

Comment: @user2567273: Right, so this is exactly what I was talking about. You even got the naming of methods correctly (self-explanatory). All you need to do is convert `public sub createArrayFromMachine()` to a function, returning an array you need. Then in caller code do an If branch, and set `myarray = createArrayFromFile()` or `myarray = createArrayFromMachine()`.  In each `create` you would declare a local variable which is already "empty", use it & return. This will replace a reference of myarray. When you reassign myarray, its old data will become subject of garbage collection (automatically).

Comment: I guess I can do that. It's a gui so my eventhandlers are the "script" that calls all of the related functions. So one button is the import button and then another button sends that data to the db. If you didn't import anything it assumes you want data from the machine and goes that same route. And then it waits for more button presses. After data is sent to the db is does a bunch of clean up (reset graphs and other objects). I'll try to find a way of what you're talking about when I get back. Wish I could upvote your comment.

Comment: @user2567273: You should be able to upvote answers when you get to 15 reputation.

Comment: You're comment is at last upvoted @Neolisk. ♥